# A regexp to ensure there's some text besides HTML tags and whitespace characters?

Tags: regex

I need to ensure that a message (i.e. a string) coming from a user does contain some text besides HTML tags and whitespace characters, so it won't be totally empty when it will be shown.

Comment: Please do provide what you have tried and where are you facing the issue.

Comment: I have tried doing the same thing using a programming language's functions, but it is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Sector - in what language?

Comment: @karthikselvaraj in JavaScript

Comment: please check below regex. I not good enough to code in javascript. howevere this is the regex

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the matches empty using this regex and cehck.

```
(?:<[^>]+?>|\s+)
```

**In Javascript**

```
your_string= your_string.replace(/(?:<[^>]+?>|\s+)/img, "");
```

after that check if `your_string` is empty

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I need a regexp that would return true/false depending on whether there's text (if that's possible) because it would be much easier to work with it.

Comment: @Sector - we can not achieve that by purely using regex, we have to do some code work. checking if string is empty is not big deal.

Comment: In the PHP-framework that I'm using, adding a validation rule consisting of a single regexp check would require about 1-3 lines of code, while writing a custom validator, which does a couple of things (like replacing & checking), would result in dozens of lines. But since it's not possible, there won't probably be a better solution than yours.

P.S. Thank you for your regexp, but it doesn't remove stuff like &nbsp;. If it does, I will mark your answer as the best.

Comment: In your question you told to remove only html tags.

Comment: "A regexp to ensure there's some text besides HTML tags and whitespace characters?"
"whitespace characters"
English is not my native language, but stuff like &nbsp; is what I tried to say by "whitespace charasters".

Comment: is there any pattern for stuff like this `&nbsp;`?